# Цикл работающий если приложение работает

Tags: c++, winapi

Нужно сделать цикл который будет работать с задержкой до тех пор пока процесс abc.exe не будет завершен.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[вот](https://quikluacsharp.ru/c-c-osnovy/uznat-iz-programmy-c-c-zapushhen-li-na-kompyutere-protsess-programma/) и [вот](https://www.cyberforum.ru/win-api/thread619789.html)

```cpp
// функция для проверки, запущен ли процесс
bool IsProcessRun(const char * const processName)
{
   HANDLE hSnapshot = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, 0);
 
   PROCESSENTRY32 pe;
   pe.dwSize = sizeof(PROCESSENTRY32);
   Process32First(hSnapshot, &pe);
 
   while (true) {
      if (strcmp(pe.szExeFile, processName) == 0) return true;
      if (!Process32Next(hSnapshot, &pe)) return false;
   }
}
```

Использование:

```cpp
while (IsProcessRun("abc.exe")) {
    //...
}
```

Comment: `E0167 аргумент типа "WCHAR *" несовместим с параметром типа "const char *"`